# Can't get image from native gallery

Tags: android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, android-gallery

I've created a test app to understand how to call the native gallery, select an image and display it on an imageView.

**1st test**

I had a simple setup. One activity and a fragment(residing within that activity) that has a button(calls gallery intent) and an imageView for the selected image. This worked perfectly.

**2nd test**

Changed the setup a bit by adding another activity and a tab host to the main activity. This new empty activity would be the launching activity and it's only purpose was to switch to the main activity that holds the fragment that calls the gallery intent. Everything works fine until I select the image from the gallery. Once the image is selected, it doesn't go back to the my test app. It's like a weird soft crash. Logcat doesn't display any errors so it's a bit hard to troubleshoot. I also placed a breakpoint on each line of the `OnActivityResult` override but they never hit.

I was hoping somebody would shed light on this matter.

SDK version is 23 and build tools is 23.0.3

Heres what I got so far:

**Main2Activity**(Launching activity)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        ActivityConfig.CreateActivity(MainActivity.class, this, true);
    }
```

In case you were wondering what `CreateActivity` does:

```
public static void CreateActivity(Class activityClass, Context context,
                                      boolean finishPreviousActivity)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, activityClass);

        if (finishPreviousActivity)
        {
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        }

        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**MainActivity**(I only use the third position on the tabhost. That's where the fragment is)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

        tabHost.setup();

        tabHost.addTab(Tabs.CreateTab("T1", R.id.tabFrag2, tabHost));

        tabHost.addTab(Tabs.CreateTab("T2", R.id.tabFrag3, tabHost));

        tabHost.addTab(Tabs.CreateTab("T3", R.id.tabFrag, tabHost));

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }
```

**Fragment**

```
private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

        Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.Btn);

        imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.Img);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                intent.setType("image/*");

                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 100)
            imageView.setImageURI(data.getData());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After much trail an error I noticed that after selecting an image it was going back to the launching activity, but not through `onCreate` or it's overridden `onActivityResult`. It was going through `onResult`. My conclusion was redesign the whole interface in a way that only one activity was required